# Get all input boxes and take their attribute values

Tags: javascript, getattribute

I have a list of checkboxes which when checked I should get them and should retrieve their attribute values.

```
res.querySelectorAll('.node:checked')
```

Which gives me an array of checked input elements, I can use for loop to iterate through this array of elements and do

```
getAttribute('data-keyvalue')
```

on each. But is it possible to get them in one line only, something in

```
querySelectorAll
```

Comment: Not really one line, but it seems like a job for `Array.prototype.foreach`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: NodeLists are not Arrays though.

Comment: @Touffy, oops! They still have a `forEach` method though

Comment: yes, although that only comes with the latest version of DOM, which defines NodeLists as iterables with forEach(), @@iterator, and values(). Using the @@iterator you can actually turn them into an array by using spread: `[...nodelist].map()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#from` to convert output which is `NodeList` of `querySelectorAll` into array and then use `array#map` to get the `data-keyvalue` attribute of the checked checkbox.

```js
var checkboxAttributes = Array.from(document
  .querySelectorAll('.node:checked'))
  .map(input => input.getAttribute('data-keyvalue'));
console.log(checkboxAttributes);
```

```html
<input class="node" data-keyvalue="7" type="checkbox" checked>
<input class="node" data-keyvalue="8" type="checkbox">
<input class="node" data-keyvalue="9" type="checkbox" checked>
<input class="node" data-keyvalue="10" type="checkbox" checked>
<input class="node" data-keyvalue="11" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `console`, it will log an array of checked data attributes values.

```js
var chk = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.node:checked')).map(function(node) {
  return node.getAttribute('data-keyvalue');
})
console.log(chk);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="node" checked data-keyvalue="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="node" checked data-keyvalue="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="node" checked data-keyvalue="3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="node" data-keyvalue="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="node" data-keyvalue="5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="node" checked data-keyvalue="6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="node" checked data-keyvalue="7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, in the end all my searching amounted to, you have to process them one at a time and build either an array or string yourself. Try creating a function that does this for you and whenever you need to get them all, the function will give you data in the format you need.